# Are these matrices simultaneously diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in M_{n,m}$ with $n\geq m$ and $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \dots \geq \sigma_m$ be the singular values of $A$. let 
$$\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 \\
& \sigma_2 \\
&& \ddots \\
&&& \sigma_m \\
0 & \dots & \dots &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Prove that if $A^*A = B^*B$ then there exist unitary matrices $X,Y \in M_n$ and $W \in M_m$ such that $A=X \Sigma W^*$ and $B = Y \Sigma W^*$.

I understand that I can get a decomposition of this form for each matrix via the singular value decomposition, however what I'm having trouble showing is that the $W^*$ works for both matrices $A$ and $B$.

In the steps of the of the proof of the singular value decomposition the $W^*$ arises from diagonalizing the matrix $UA$ where $U$ is unitary, and so I figured if I could show that $UA$ and $VB$ commute I would be done.

The $U$ and $V$ are obtained by noting that $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ are unitary similar and similarly with $B^*B = BB^*$

Thus I need to show that $UAVB = VBUA$ which I have not been able to pull off. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: The term is *matrix*.  One matrix, many matrices, but there's no such thing as a matrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the SVD of $A,B$:

$A=X\Sigma W^*,B=Y\Sigma_1 {W_1}^*$. The ${\sigma_i}^2$ are the non-zero eigenvalues of $A^*A=B^*B$. Then $\Sigma=\Sigma_1$.

The columns of $W_1$ are a set of orthonormal eigenvectors of $B^*B$ associated to the ordering of the $\sigma_i$. Then we may choose $W_1=W$.

Note that the columns of $Y$ are a set of orthonormal eigenvectors of $BB^*$ associated to the ordering of the $\sigma_i$ and that, in general, $AA^*\not= BB^*$. In these conditions, we cannot choose for $Y$ any unitary matrix.